# Connect with Google Speech API

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I am trying to execute Google Speech API through web request, C#.

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.
>   System.Net.WebException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a send.   Source=AP.Voice   StackTrace:
>          at AP.Voice.SpeechConvertor.ToText(String file, Int32 bitRate, String language, UInt32 maxresults) 
>          Message=Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.MultipleWrite(BufferOffsetSize[]
>   buffers)

Here is the code snippet of the main function:

```
 public static VoiceTextResult ToText(string file, int bitRate = DEFAULT_BIT_RATE,
        string language = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, uint maxresults = 1)
    {

        /*
         * Base address - https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize
         * xjerr  - sending 1 would tell google server to return errors along with json response and not an http error code
         * client - it can be anything, or your application name, however the practice is to call through chromium string.
         * language - default is set to en-US; it can be used with other languages that google recog.
         * maxresult - The maxmum number of hypotheses to be returned, default is set to 1.
         * pfilter filter=0 
         * 
         * This is a funny one. Google (by default) censors the results, leading to “Please search for ###” (pfilter!=0) instead of 
         * Please search for s e x” (pfilter=0).
         */
        NameValueCollection nc = new NameValueCollection();
        nc.Set("xjerr", "1");
        nc.Set("client", DEFAULT_CLIENT);
        nc.Set("lang", language);
        nc.Set("maxresults", maxresults.ToString());
        nc.Set("pfilter", "0");

        HttpWebRequest request =
                (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
                    "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?" + SpeechConvertor.ToQueryString(nc) );

        request.Proxy = null;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                        delegate { return true; };

        request.Timeout = 106000;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=" + bitRate;
        request.UserAgent = DEFAULT_CLIENT;

        byte[] data;
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(
                                            file,
                                            FileMode.Open,
                                            FileAccess.Read))
        {
            data = new byte[fStream.Length];
            fStream.Read(data, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
            fStream.Close();
        }

        using (Stream wrStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            wrStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        string requestResult = "";
        try
        {
            var response = ((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream();

            if (response != null)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response);
                requestResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();
                response.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            throw ee;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestResult))
        {
            return null;
        }

        VoiceTextResult SR = new VoiceTextResult();
        SR.FromJSON(requestResult);
        return SR;
    }
```